# Axios Interceptors with given token, React

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios, token, interceptor

After this request:

```
   axios
  .post(url_auth, obj)
  .then(response => {

    const info = response.data
    this.setState({info})

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I store inside ***info*** a JSON with id and token. (backend sent it to me)

I would like now to store token in the ***headers*** of every request I made.

How do I make it with? I guess with ***interceptor***? Once I configure the headers inside the interceptor (I'm trying to understand how), how do I call it in my request?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done with the interceptors.Refer this [article](https://dev.to/teroauralinna/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor-30ae) 

Also you can refer one of my [repo](https://github.com/prabhatmishra33/ShoppingSiteMeanJSApp/blob/master/src/app/shared/auth.interceptor.ts),The project is in Angular & Node.Used Token for validating the request

Comment: Could you add an example of code here, because I'm finding lot of documentation but I don't understand the 2 point in my question. (How to I add token and id to the interceptor, and how I call this configuration in my future requests)

Comment: this article https://medium.com/swlh/handling-access-and-refresh-tokens-using-axios-interceptors-3970b601a5da has most of it ,what i meant.

Comment: How do I pass username and password if I code the interceptor outside of my class?

Comment: for signup and signin interceptors won't be doing anything, it will be purely the container level login and post api's, interceptors however wil intercept these requests too but for sign in or signup there would not be any token hence token won't be added in the header, for other api requests the token will be added as it will be delivered by the backend server and stored in your localStorage.